# GET/POST $string?

Tags: php

I need help to post and get the points of the string `$points` in the next site..

currently it is so:

> question1.php **1 *point(s)*** -> submit -> question2.php **0 *point(s)***

but it must be so:

> question1.php **1 *point*(s)** -> submit -> question2.php **1 *point(s)***

```
<?PHP $_POST ($points); ?>
```

should I do it that way?

Comment: Your want to store your *points* in [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) other super globals are open to manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is pass the variable `$points` from one file to another? You are correct in using `$_POST` and `$_GET` to pass these variables but there are other issues that I should point out. First let me answer your question.

`$_POST` and `$_GET` are simply arrays of information. `$_POST` is data that is set in the headers of the request and passed without changing the URL of the page. `$_GET` are parameters in the URL (usually you see them as **www.url.com?data=value&otherdata=value**).

The values are store in the array with a key. This is simply a text string, in your example this text string would be 'points'. You can pass points to the new file by simply adding it to the URL:

**www.url.com/?question2.php?points=1**

You can retrieve the vaules in the new file with:

```
$points = $_GET['points'];
```

and that will give you what you want.

**Now for the issues...**

Since you would be passing them in `$_GET`, anyone can just change the value and set new points. This can also be done, with slightly more difficulty with `$_POST` but essentially it is the same problem. A better way would be to use [PHP sessions](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/sessions.shtml), but this depends on how worried you are about people changing the data. If it is not crucial that people are unable to change the data, you could always just [obfuscate it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) or [encrypt it](http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/simple-php-encrypt-and-decrypt/).

You are also using multiple files. Now, without seeing the files I can't say that this is a bad methodology, but I can say that you may want to, instead, create a single file that can handle all the questions (aka, a handler). You can pass the values in the same way, and just make your form actionless (so that it submits to itself). This will give you the `$_POST` and `$_GET` data you want, without the need for multiple files.

I know this might give you more questions than answers, but it should at least get you pointed in the right direction!